# Is it possible to have nested application in single spa framework?

Tags: single-spa

What i am looking at is having a angular microfront-end inside another react microfront-end, is this something we can achieve from single-spa

Comment: yes this is possible. there are lots of ways of doing it. here's an example with glimmer https://dev.to/rajasegar/micro-frontends-with-glimmer-js-and-single-spa-42aa

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this can be done two ways. It depends on the frameworks being used by your applications.

## Option 1: Cross microfrontend imports

See the [Single-spa documentation on cross microfrontend imports here](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#cross-microfrontend-imports).
This option is ideal if your applications are using the same framework, and uses the simplicity of normal `import` statements.

## Option 2: Single-spa Parcels

See the [Single-spa documentation on Parcels here](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/parcels-overview/). This option is ideal if you need to cross-framework support, but Parcels are harder to use and understand so we generally don't recommend using them unless you're sure that's needed.

(As an aside, many people *think* they need to embed on microfrontend in another, but this isn't always true and you might be able to solve your requirement in a different way; depends on your use case).